# How to simply pull information from excel to use as a variable ruby

Tags: ruby, excel, spreadsheet, information-retrieval

I am trying to pull product ID's, that are in Excel, into ruby to use as a temporary variable. I cannot find a simple solution and am not sure if I should use the spreadsheet gem or axlsx gem. If you guys could help get me started that would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to save the excel document as a csv. Then it would be relatively easy to to open the file with your ruby program, read in the data you need and put that into a variable, for example using the CSV library

```
CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv") do |row|
  # use row here
end
```

Comment: What do I put for the row? like 

row.3 
and it will eventually be in an array format?

Comment: row itself is an array of a row in the excel document. So if your sheet has columns ( id, firstname, lastname ) You would access the id with row[0]